# Control A character delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle, special-characters, delimiter, spool

How to spool oracle table records with control A character as delimiter through sql script in linux?

I have tried as below

```
Spool file.dat
Select column 1 ||'\u0001'||,
column2 ||'\u0001'||,
column3 from table
spool off
```

Also as

```
Spool file.dat
Select column 1 ||'^A'||,
column2 ||'^A'||,
column3 from table
spool off
```

But delimiter is coming as a string literal,
How can this be done??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would attempt Select column 1 || chr(01) ||.  See (http://www.windmill.co.uk/ascii-control-codes.html) chr uses the two digit decimal value to specify special characters such as this.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson - Thanks a lot! working in my case.